# bar is not visible when task duration is less than 30 minutes

Tags: javascript

I'm using https://github.com/anto-christo/gantt/tree/hour-view-mode for gantt chart. I displayed several bar(tasks) in one row. For example, I have two tasks and displayed in one row. Works good, but when task is too short, I don't see bar.

```
[
    {
        "custom_index": 0,
        "id": "139_15",
        "name": "Blue machine",
        "start": "2024-03-19 20:49:56",
        "end": "2024-03-19 21:50:31",
        "progress": 0,
        "_start": "2024-03-19T19:49:56.000Z",
        "_end": "2024-03-19T20:50:31.000Z", // bar visible
        "_index": 0,
        "dependencies": []
    },
    {
        "custom_index": 0,
        "id": "139_15",
        "name": "Blue machine",
        "start": "2024-03-19 21:20:31",
        "end": "2024-03-20 00:49:56",
        "progress": 31,
        "_start": "2024-03-19T20:20:31.000Z",
        "_end": "2024-03-19T23:49:56.000Z",
        "_index": 0,
        "dependencies": []
    }
]
```

[image]

```
[
    {
        "custom_index": 0,
        "id": "139_15",
        "name": "Frezarka 1 - Niebieska",
        "start": "2024-03-19 20:49:56",
        "end": "2024-03-19 21:20:31",
        "progress": 0,
        "_start": "2024-03-19T19:49:56.000Z",
        "_end": "2024-03-19T20:20:31.000Z", //bar not visible now
        "_index": 0,
        "dependencies": []
    },
    {
        "custom_index": 0,
        "id": "139_15",
        "name": "Frezarka 1 - Niebieska",
        "start": "2024-03-19 21:20:31",
        "end": "2024-03-20 00:49:56",
        "progress": 33,
        "_start": "2024-03-19T20:20:31.000Z",
        "_end": "2024-03-19T23:49:56.000Z",
        "_index": 0,
        "dependencies": []
    }
]
```

[image]

Is there any way to make the short task bar also visible?
Full code of index.js
[https://jsfiddle.net/ze7x9w6v/1/](https://stackoverflow.com)

```
    update_view_scale(view_mode) {
        this.options.view_mode = view_mode;
        if (view_mode === VIEW_MODE.HOUR) {
            this.options.step = 24 / 24;
            this.options.column_width = 38;
        } else if (view_mode === VIEW_MODE.DAY) {
            this.options.step = 24;
            this.options.column_width = 38;
        } else if (view_mode === VIEW_MODE.HALF_DAY) {
            this.options.step = 24 / 2;
            this.options.column_width = 38;
        } else if (view_mode === VIEW_MODE.QUARTER_DAY) {
            this.options.step = 24 / 4;
            this.options.column_width = 38;
        } else if (view_mode === VIEW_MODE.WEEK) {
            this.options.step = 24 * 7;
            this.options.column_width = 140;
        } else if (view_mode === VIEW_MODE.MONTH) {
            this.options.step = 24 * 30;
            this.options.column_width = 120;
        } else if (view_mode === VIEW_MODE.YEAR) {
            this.options.step = 24 * 365;
            this.options.column_width = 120;
        }
    }
```

`    setup_gantt_dates() {
this.gantt_start = this.gantt_end = null;

```
    for (let task of this.tasks) {
        // set global start and end date
        if (!this.gantt_start || task._start < this.gantt_start) {
            this.gantt_start = task._start;
        }
        if (!this.gantt_end || task._end > this.gantt_end) {
            this.gantt_end = task._end;
        }
    }

    this.gantt_start = date_utils.start_of(this.gantt_start, 'day');
    this.gantt_end = date_utils.start_of(this.gantt_end, 'day');

    // add date padding on both sides
    if (this.view_is([VIEW_MODE.HOUR, VIEW_MODE.QUARTER_DAY, VIEW_MODE.HALF_DAY])) {
        this.gantt_start = date_utils.add(this.gantt_start, -7, 'day');
        this.gantt_end = date_utils.add(this.gantt_end, 7, 'day');
    } else if (this.view_is(VIEW_MODE.MONTH)) {
        this.gantt_start = date_utils.start_of(this.gantt_start, 'year');
        this.gantt_end = date_utils.add(this.gantt_end, 1, 'year');
    } else if (this.view_is(VIEW_MODE.YEAR)) {
        this.gantt_start = date_utils.add(this.gantt_start, -2, 'year');
        this.gantt_end = date_utils.add(this.gantt_end, 2, 'year');
    } else {
        this.gantt_start = date_utils.add(this.gantt_start, -1, 'month');
        this.gantt_end = date_utils.add(this.gantt_end, 1, 'month');
    }
}`
```